# How to fetch data with time limit in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, r, datetime

I am having below the mentioned table in MySql.

```
ID       UniqueId     Date
T-1      AT-1         2018-04-03 15:16:48
T-2      AT-1         2018-04-10 18:21:24
T-3      AT-1         2018-04-22 13:05:16
T-4      AT-2         2018-05-05 17:12:04
T-5      AT-2         2018-05-15 05:03:01
T-6      AT-2         2018-05-25 06:09:23
T-7      AT-3         2018-06-01 06:09:23
T-8      AT-3         2018-06-25 06:09:23
T-9      AT-3         2018-07-01 06:09:23
```

I want to fetch only those record where the latest `ID` basis on the `UniqueId` are older than or equal to 10 days.

For Example, `ID` T3 is the latest `ID` for `UniqueId` `AT-2` basis on date and the difference between immediate `ID` T2 is 12 days.

Also, If this is possible with R that would also work :)

Expected Output:

```
ID       UniqueId     Date                  Difference
T-3      AT-1         2018-04-22 13:05:16   12
T-6      AT-2         2018-05-25 06:09:23   10
```

Comment: what is your mysql version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to check the conditions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    -- no newer row exists
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS n
    WHERE n.UniqueId = t.UniqueId
    AND n.Date > t.Date
) AND NOT EXISTS (
    -- no older row exists that has difference of less than 10 days
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS o
    WHERE o.UniqueId = t.UniqueId
    AND o.Date < t.Date
    AND o.Date >= t.Date - INTERVAL 10 DAY
)
```

Comment: As long as OP doesn't want the actual difference in days this is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you the results you want. It `JOIN`s the table first to a derived table of the `MAX(Date)` for each `UniqueId`, and then to itself using the condition that the `Date` value is the latest `Date` less than the maximum value. Finally the `WHERE` clause filters out those dates that are not at least 10 days later:

```
SELECT t1.*, DATEDIFF(t1.date, t3.date) AS Difference
FROM test t1
JOIN (SELECT UniqueId, MAX(Date) AS Date
      FROM test
      GROUP BY UniqueID) t2 ON t2.UniqueId = t1.UniqueId AND t2.Date = t1.Date
LEFT JOIN test t3 ON t3.UniqueId = t1.UniqueId
                  AND t3.Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) 
                                 FROM test t4 
                                 WHERE t4.UniqueId = t3.UniqueId
                                   AND t4.Date < t2.Date)
WHERE DATEDIFF(t1.date, t3.date) >= 10
```

Output:

```
ID      UniqueId    Date                    Difference
T-3     AT-1        2018-04-22 13:05:16     12
T-6     AT-2        2018-05-25 06:09:23     10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/BjwoQprDKwtvRfvcGSy3p/0)

Comment: How can i get the count of `UniqueId` as a separate column (i.e for `T-3` UniqueId count would be 3.

Comment: @VectorJX see this updated demo:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/BjwoQprDKwtvRfvcGSy3p/1